# matplotlib - mask portion of standalone colorbar

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

Below is the code to build a standalone continuous colorbar. I would like to mask, with black, all values between -3 and 3.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, .25))
cmap = mpl.cm.twilight
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-9.6, vmax=9.6)
cbar = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal', ticks=[-3,3])
```

[image]

Comment: May I ask what the purpose of this would be? It seems undesireable, because you couldn't distinguish values at the lower end (around -9.6) from those between -3 and 3. Hence any resulting plot would be very hard to decipher.

Comment: This is true, thank you. I'll instead use a colormap with black centered at 0 such as mpl.cm.twilight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`colors.ListedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap) creates a new colormap from a list of colors. The following code retrieves these colors from an existing map and makes the desired modifications:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('twilight', 256)
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-9.6, vmax=9.6)
maskedcolors = cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
black = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])
maskedcolors[int(round(norm(-3) * 256)) : int(round(norm(3) * 256)) + 1] = black
maskedcmp = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(maskedcolors)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, .5))
cbar = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=maskedcmp, norm=norm, orientation='horizontal', ticks=[-3, 3])
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: the modified colorbar]